# How to sort multi-dimensional array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to sort this array by `pos` attribute **even though keys** (`name, store_id, product etc.`)

```
[Attributes] => Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 30
        )

    [store_id] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 10
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 20
        )

)
```

**Edit:** performance is important of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `uasort()` which lets you define your sorting logic and also maintains your associative indexes. Please note that it changes your original array and only returns a boolean based on success.

```
uasort($your_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['pos'] > $b['pos'];
});
```

My example works >= PHP 5.3 , but for older versions you can use a normal compare function as well.

See [`uasort()` Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) for details.

Comment: can you check your code with this sample (it is almost the same with above structure): 
`$attr['Attr']['name']['pos'] = 30;
$attr['Attr']['price']['pos'] = 10;
$attr['Attr']['desc']['pos'] = 20;`

Comment: @dino You could have provided the exact specs you need in your question :). What do you want to sort here? You could try inserting `$attr['Attr']` in place of `$your_array`.

Comment: @baz.. - Sweet Jesus. sometimes my brain doesn't work :) It works well. thanks a loot

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the PHP function `array_multisort`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

There is an example-function in the comments, which should be fine for you:

```
function array_orderby()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $data = array_shift($args);
    foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
        if (is_string($field)) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $row)
                $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
            $args[$n] = $tmp;
            }
    }
    $args[] = &$data;
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
    return array_pop($args);
}

// $dataArray is the array that contains your data
$sorted = array_orderby($dataArray, 'pos', SORT_DESC);
```

Comment: @Jung - I didn't do it actually... consider there are a couple of more keys and like these structure that I need to order. So how can I manage it with array_multisort? Should I change structure? or better idea?

Comment: Actually its not as simple as I though first. But looking at the linked page you find an example in the comments, which I just added to my answer. This should sort $dataArray by 'pos' descending

Comment: @Jung - somethings wrong with your example. Actually i didn't sort it even though I provided the exact specs using your function.

Comment: Looks like a bit overkill for this one.